# Tkinter Display Stopwatch hours, seconds and minutes

Tags: tkinter, time, display, duration, stopwatch

Trying to properly display currently running stopwatch time so it shows Hours:Minutes:Seconds after I press the start button. My code works only until it reaches a minute then it displays just a 1, I'm not sure how I would reset seconds to 0 again and still show the minute section. I know I need to increment it but it will end up showing the wrong time. Also I'm trying to make another if statement so when 60 minutes go by it will show the hours. Overall output ex: Current run time is 1 hour, 5 minutes and 20 seconds display would show -> 01:05:20. *Edit* How can I stop the timer then save the current time into a string variable?

```
import tkinter as tink
import datetime
seconds = -1
run = False
def var_name(mark):
   def value():
      if run:
         global seconds
         # Just beore starting
         if seconds == -1:
            show = "Starting"
         else:
            show = str(seconds)
         mark['text'] = show
         #Increment the count after
         #every 1 second
         mark.after(1000, value)
         seconds += 1
         if (seconds > 60):
            minutes = seconds // 60
            seconds = 0
            SecAMin = str(minutes), ":", str(seconds)
            show = SecAMin
            #show = str(minutes)
            mark['text'] = show
   value()

   def Stop():
   global run
   start['state'] = 'normal'
   stop['state'] = 'disabled'
   reset['state'] = 'normal'
   run = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the hours and minutes based on the value of `seconds` and don't need to reset `seconds` to 0.  Also use argument instead of global variable.

```py
def var_name(mark, seconds=-1):
   def value(seconds=seconds):
      if run:
         # Just before starting
         if seconds == -1:
            show = "Starting"
         else:
            mins, secs = divmod(seconds, 60)
            hrs, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
            show = f"{hrs:02}:{mins:02}:{secs:02}"
         mark['text'] = show
         #Increment the count after
         #every 1 second
         mark.after(1000, value, seconds+1)
   value()
```

Comment: You always have the best and easy to read code, thank you so much I really appreciate it

Comment: One more question how would I save the current value (hours:minutes:seconds) so I can store it in a variable, so I can use it later?

Comment: You need to use global variables for your current design.

Comment: so am I making all variables global at the top?  Then am I reusing the variable show to print it or re-use it for later?

Comment: It is better to create another new question instead of adding the new question into this question.

Comment: Thanks and I figured it out, just needed to make show global and it works fine. Thanks again